# Arduino PCB etchable pdf

Tags: arduino

Where I live, one cannot buy an Arduino very cheaply. I figure, if I make one for my own purpose on a pcb then it would be much cheaper and would be much more fun. I cannot find any etchable PDF on the internet so can anyone point me to one?

Comment: It's hard to imagine a place on earth where it would be cheaper to make your own PCB instead of ordering an Arduino on eBay. But, hey, more fun - that's a sure thing :-) !

Comment: actually I don't know the price to get a PCB constructed in the market here, but I was talking about the toner transfer method to try at home

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a single-sided arduino PCB that you can etch at home:

http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardSerialSingleSided

A smaller alternative is the Really Bare Bones Board (RBBB), it's Arduino compatible and comes with design files:

http://www.moderndevice.com/products/rbbb-kit

Or, you could do without a PCB and go for a Paperduino:

http://lab.guilhermemartins.net/2009/05/06/paperduino-prints/

Comment: I really liked the paperduino idea, its just perfect for my purposes (if i could get it to work)

Answer (score 5):

In fact, the layout files to (almost) all the Arduino boards are available on their respective pages, linked here: http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Hardware

I would recommend the updated version of the Arduino Single-Sided Serial board, described here: http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardSerialSingleSided3

Comment: ok i have this doubt, I have an old computer which actually has a serial port. Now is it necessary that I add the usb converter? Will that make any difference to the software?

Comment: The software on the PC talks to a "COM port".
It neither knows nor cares that the serial bits are being translated to USB packets by a PC device driver, sent down the USB cable, and translated back to serial bits by the FTDI chip.
The software would work exactly the same with a standard PC RS232 serial port connected to a serial cable with some sort of 12 V RS232 - to - RS232-TTL converter, such as the MAX232.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that the board layout files for the Arduino are available, but you can pick up the design files for the Freeduino [here](http://www.freeduino.org/freeduino_open_designs.html).  It's not the Arduino, but it should be compatible enough.  I don't know if it's the sort of thing you'd want to etch yourself at home but you're welcome to try.  So far as I saw, the boards don't come in PDF format - just Gerber and Eagle, so pick up Gerbv from Sourceforge to convert to PDF.